# Getopt not recognizing command line arguments (C program)

Tags: c, linux, centos, getopt

I am creating a C program in CentOS linux, and I cannot get my getopt to recognize arguments from the command line. I am relatively new to linux and C.

The error I get is 'command not found'
I compiled the file using gcc and executing with ./testFile
compile command was: gcc mathwait.c -o testFile and then ./testFile

thanks for your help!

```
void help()
{
 printf("The options for this program are:\n ");
 printf("-h - walkthrough of options and program intent\n ");
 printf("This program forks off a single child process to do a task\n ");
 printf("The main process will wait for it to complete and then do\n");
 printf("some additional work\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int option;
 while((option = getopt(argc, argv, "h")) != -1)
{
  switch(option)
 {
  case 'h':
   help();
  break;
  default:
   help();
  break;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the command you used to compile your program.  "Command not found" usually means the OS is unable to locate your executable.  It could be you didn't tell the compiler to change the name of the executable to "testFile"... the default name is "a.out".

Comment: gcc mathwait.c -o testFile

Comment: Sure it compiled? That's missing a few needed `#include`s...

Comment: Yes, accidentally omitted the include statements. I can see the testFile in my directory.

Comment: If you run `./testFile`, you are not providing any arguments.  Run `./textile -h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are missing the two header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

and you are missing a return statement:

```
return 0;
```

2. Per getopt(3) man page:

> If  there  are no more option characters, getopt() returns -1

This means if you don't supply any arguments `getopt()` will return -1 and you `while()` loop is not being executed and your program will exit.  If you call your program with `-h` the first case will be executed, otherwise (meaning any other arguments) the `default` case will be executed.

3. I assume this is test code, otherwise there is no point of having a switch when you do the same thing in all cases.
4. Formatting matters for readability:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void help() {
    printf(
        "The options for this program are:\n"
        "-h - walkthrough of options and program intent\n"
        "This program forks off a single child process to do a task\n"
        "The main process will wait for it to complete and then do\n"
        "some additional work\n"
    );
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int option;
    while((option = getopt(argc, argv, "h")) != -1) {
        switch(option) {
            case 'h':
                help();
                break;
            default:
                help();
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> compile command was: `gcc mathwait.c -o testFile` and then `./testFile`

If you run `./testFile`, you are not providing any arguments. Run:

```
./testFile -h
```

Now you provide an option for `getopt()` to process.  If you ran `./testFile -x`, you'd get a message about an unrecognized option `'x'` and then the information from the `help()` function.